# Replace string in query parameter in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

Preset:
got a gallery script that is creating thumbnails like so:

```
GET /path/to/script/thumb.php?src=host.tld/path/to/file.jpg
```

Goal:
rewrite the hostname in src to a different name:

```
GET /path/to/script/thumb.php?src=newhost.tld/path/to/file.jpg
```

It's only the host that I need replaced, everything else should stay the same.

I've tried a couple of things but nothing produces the result that I want.

This is the code as it is now (not working):

```
location ~* thumb {
    if ($args ~ "(src=http://host.tld:8080/)(.*)" ) {
        set $params $2;
        rewrite ^.*$ thumb.php?src=http://newhost.tld/$params? last;
    }
}
```

also, host.tld could be just about anything so matching on host.tld literally is just a simplification for now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17391446/6309 can give you clues. `$args` seems be start with the `?`.